# CUDA 11.8 and Pytorch with RTX 3060 (Not working GPU as compute engine)

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use my GPU as compute engine with Pytorch.

I have all the drivers (522.25) with CUDA 11.8 installed in my local machine, but Pytorch can't recognize my GPU.

I'll attach images from my noteebok cells and my CMD with NVIDIA-SMI command.

[image: My notebook]

[image: NVIDIA-SMI]

I will appreciate any kind of help or info regarding this issue.

I installed CUDA and all the drivers needed in my local machine and I expected to run Pytorch with my GPU, but when I checked, Pytorch is using my CPU instead of my GPU.

Comment: You have installed a build of PyTorch which doesn’t have GPU support compiled in

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have Pytorch 1.13, it's the latest version. Should I downgrade my version in order to use GPU? Isn't it better to use always the last version?

Comment: It is not the version you have, it is the build. The id string “1.13+cpu” means you Installed a cpu only build.

Comment: Thank you talonmies. How can I install a GPU build as you saying? Sorry bothering but I'm reading bunch of documentation in Nvidia or blogs and trying to find any solution but I can't resolve this..

Comment: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Answer (score -3):

Lastest pytorch is supported at cuda version 11.6 ...
You can check it this link below
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel_22-02.html

Comment: (a) That is the CUDA version supplied with NVIDIA's deep learning container image, not anything related to the official PyTorch releases, and (b) the OP has installed a CPU only build, so what CUDA version is supported is completely irrelevant